# What does the GetSiblingItemsAndContainers silverlight method do?

Tags: silverlight

I found an extension method, GetSiblingItemsAndContainers for TreeViewItems.

I cannot, however, find anything about it on msdn.

What does this method do?

Comment: I found this in intellisense, as JustinAngel mentioned, it's a part of the Silverlight Toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the Silverlight Toolkit March 2009 release we shipped TreeViewExtensions.
Which is a class filled to the brim with extension methods for TreeView.

You can see a copy of the source code for that class in the [Nov09 TreeViewExtensions release here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/35261#779495).

The method you asked about returns a List of Pairs for the TreeView.
Each pair contains the Container (the TreeViewItem) and the Item (the instance the TreeViewItem is bound to).